# What would be the most sane way to attach an event to everything on the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Let me describe the thing that I want to accomplish: I basically want to make the 'inspect element' hover effect from Firebug, so a user can eventually select content from the DOM.

I started with a naive implementation of:

```
$('div').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
}).bind('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).css('border', 'none');
});
```

This has several problems (some of which I can fix) but the immediate and most apparent is bubbling so that every parent `<div>` gets a border, and also that it's only attached to `<div>`s

Do I need to enumerate each element set that I want this event attached to? Do I need to prevent bubbling somehow so that only the upper-most element gets the event handler (and what does that look like?)

Any and all suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).bind('mouseover', function(event) {    
    $(event.target).addClass('hover');
});
```

This will attach one event handler to `document`, and events will bubble up to it where they will be handled.

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/QbMPq/).

Comment: Note that you don't need `stopPropagation()` because the event has already bubbled up to the document, and the only thing left for it to bubble to is the window.

Comment: @Neil You are right, and I don't know why I put that there! Must of been left over from the original code I wrote. Thanks for pointing that out.